# Use stdout, for run with sudo

Tags: bash, shell-script, stdout

When I type command `echo 'cd ~/Development/Web' > /usr/local/bin/webdev`, my goal is create file webdev in /usr/local/bin, I get error 'Permission denied', then change command to '`echo 'cd ~/Development/Web' > sudo /usr/local/bin/webdev`', command runs successfully my expection is that created file webdev in /usr/local/bin, but instead is create sudo file in ~. How I can run my first command, without `sudo su` and then `echo 'cd ~Devel...`?

Comment: What do you actually want to do?

Comment: @Kusalananda, updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
echo 'cd ~/Development/Web' | sudo tee /usr/local/bin/webdev
```